# Brownian motion and Cauchy distribution

Tags: probability-theory, harmonic-analysis, stochastic-analysis

Suppose that $X_t=(B_t,W_t)$ is a $BM^{d+1}$ where $B_t$ is a $d$ dimensional Brownian motion and $W_t$ is a one dimensional Brownian motion. Suppose the process $X_t$ starts at $(0,y),y>0$. Then it is a classical result that $X_{T_y}$ has Cauchy distribution where $T_y$ is the stopping time $T_y=\inf\{t>0: W_t=0\}$. My question is, what happens when $B_t$ doesnt start at 0? Like if $X_t$ starts at $(x,y)$ instead. Does $X_{T_y}$ have the same distribution? More importantly I would like to see a proof (or reference) of the result that $\Phi(x,y)=\int_{R^d} \rho(x,y,z)f(z)dz$ is harmonic where $\rho$ is the density of $X_{T_y}$ and $f\in C_c(R^n)$.

Comment: I think you might be confusing some things here.  If $X_t$ starts at $(0,y)$, then $\inf\{t > 0 : W_t = y\} = 0$, so $X_{T_y} = 0$.  I'm not sure what you mean by $X_{W_y}$.  $W_y$, i.e. $W$ at time $y$, could be negative, so what would $X$ at a negative time mean?  When you ask that $\Phi(x,y)$ is harmonic, you refer to a function $f$ that isn't defined anywhere.  What is $f$?

Comment: Yep, fixed a bunch of typos. Thanks for letting me know.